# DenormalizerInterface denormalize Cache key contains reserved characters {}()/\@: Entities with associations

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine, denormalization

I have this Exception when try to convert array to object with associations.
In Contact entity is construct with Company entity.

**EXCEPTION**:

> Cache key "pAppBundle\Entity\Companyid" contains reserved characters {}()/\@:

Controller:

```
class ContactController extends AbstractController
{
    public function newAction(Request $request, Company $company, DenormalizerInterface $denormalizer)
    {
        $data = $request->get('contact');

        $data['company'] = $company;

        $denormalizer->denormalize($data, Contact::class);
    }
}
```

Entity Company:

```
class Company {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Contact", mappedBy="company", cascade={"ALL"})
     */
    private $contacts;
}
```

Entity Contact:

```
class Contact {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="text")
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="contacts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $company;

    public function __construct(Company $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
        $this->files = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue with a scenario that is very very comparable. Seems like a bug in the Symfony cache component. Do you have a solution yet?

Comment: I'm waiting :) https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26961